# I am wondering why template method can call non-template method?

Tags: c++

I am newbie to c++ template. If I defined a template method, which I found I can call non template method

for example

```
void non_template(double x)
{
}

template<typename T>
void testClass<T>::method1() {
   /*****/
   T var1;
   //call a nontemplate here using var1
   non_template(var1);
}
```

I am not sure why this can be allowed without any compilation errors; If my var1 is int, will it be wrong?

Comment: There will be compilation errors if you instantiate the template with a typpe `T` that is not convertible to double.

Comment: Imagine a template like a glorified macro. If after the replacement of T the code can be compiled, there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure why this can be allowed without any compilation errors; If my var1 is int, will it be wrong?

Template classes and functions work slightly differently from non-templated ones: checking for validity is done in 2 passes - once at definition time, the other at instantiation (when the method is first called) time.

When processing the template function, it checks things like syntax, and type not dependent on the template arguments. If these succeed, it will not complain and store the definition of the template in it's state.

When you try to call (instantiate) the template with a particular set of arguments, it will go back to the definition stored and recheck thing that are dependent on the type of parameters passed in.

So, if I try to call your function with an int, double and a float like:

```
 test_calls.method(5.0); // Works as expected
 test_calls.method(5); // Works, because int can be converted to double implicitly.
 test_calls.method("Hello"); // Doesn't work, because "non-templated" cannot be call with a char const* argument.
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler looks for matches by applying permitted conversions to parameters in order to find a match (i.e. a function that can be called).   That is true for all functions, not just templates.

If T is a type that can be implicitly converted to a double, then it will be so the "non template" function can be called.

If T cannot be implicitly converted to double, then the compiler will report it cannot find a match in some way.